# Recorrer objeto con .map

Tags: javascript, json, jsonobject

Tengo el siguiente objeto y quiero realizar una función para localizar el último nivel, para guardarlo y devolverlo posteriormente.

```
const products = [
  {
    name: 'products1',
    subcategories: [
      {
        name: 'products2',
        subcategories: [],
      },
      {
        name: 'products3',
        subcategories: [
          {
            name: 'products4',
            subcategories: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'products5',
    subcategories: [],
  },
];
```

Y la salida de la función quiero que muestre la ruta: *'/category1/category3/category4'* para el parámetro de búsqueda *products4* o */category5* para el name: *products5*.

Dudas:

1. ¿Cómo puedo consulta la última propiedad del objeto y devolverla? He pensado hacerlo con `filter`  y luego devolverlo con `.map` pero no logro llegar hasta el último nivel.
2. ¿Se puede recorrer un objeto inverso?

###### Edición 1, estoy intentando iterarlo de esta forma pero no voy bien encaminado.

```js
let array = [];
categories.forEach(a => {
  if (a.name == categoryName && a.subcategories.length == 0) {
    array.push(a.name);
    console.log(array);
    return;
  } else if (a.subcategories.length > 0 && a.subcategories.name != categoryName) {
    //second level
    if (a.subcategories.length > 0 && a.subcategories.name != categoryName) {
      array.push(a.name);
      //third level
      a.subcategories.forEach(c => {
        if (c.name == categoryName) {
          array.push(c.name);
          return;
        } else if (c.subcategories.length > 0 && c.subcategories.name != categoryName) {
          array.push(c.name);
          c.subcategories.forEach(d => {
            if (d.subcategories.name == categoryName) {
              array.push(d.name);
              return;
            } else if (d.subcategories.length > 0 && d.subcategories.name != categoryName)
              array.push(d.name);
            else array.push(d.name);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }

  return array;
});
```

Comment: Tal vez podrías usar un método recursivo. Has intentado algo?

Comment: No, con recursividad todavía no. Estoy intentando hacer un filter para dejarlo limpio, pero no logro nada.

Comment: Incluye todos los intentos por favor. Con eso, aumentas las chances de obtener respuesta. Se valora la investigación y los intentos de resolver el escenario. Saludos.

Comment: Hola, acabo de  añadir un avance.

Comment: Coincido con @MauricioContreras, utiliza recursividad. Estás repitiendo el mismo código una y otra y otra y otra vez... pásalo a una función y simplemente llámala mientras tengas categorías en el objeto en el que te encuentras... simple y efectivo.

Comment: Lo que te han dicho sobre recursividad es la mejor opción pero desconozco por qué no quieres utilizarla, respondiendo a tu pregunta 2 `const reversed = products.reverse();`

Comment: Muchas gracias, estaría muy agradecido si pudierais mandarme un ejemplo de recursividad de este tipo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Una función que retorne TODAS las rutas

```js
const products = [{name: 'products1',subcategories: [{name: 'products2',subcategories: []},{name: 'products3',subcategories: [{name: 'products4',subcategories: [],},],},],},{name: 'products5',subcategories: []}];

function buscar(elementos) {
    let res = [];
    for (let e of elementos) {
        res.push(e.name);
        if (e.subcategories && e.subcategories.length > 0) {
            for (let sub of buscar(e.subcategories)) {
                 res.push(e.name + "/" + sub);
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
console.log(buscar(products));
```

2. Ahora que tenemos una función que nos retorna TODAS las rutas, buscaremos por ruta, empleando la siguiente logica:

- Siendo "B" la ruta a buscar, está última debe empezar por "B"
- Siempre debemos retornar la ruta más larga (las más profunda)

```js
const products = [{name: 'products1',subcategories: [{name: 'products2',subcategories: [],},{name: 'products3',subcategories: [{name: 'products4',subcategories: [],},],},],},{name: 'products5',subcategories: [],},];

function BuscarPorRuta(ruta, array) {;
    let resp = "";
    for (let e of buscar(array)) {
        if (e.startsWith(ruta)) { //Si la ruta comienza con
            if (e.split('/').length >= resp.split('/').length) { //nos quedamos con la ruta mas profunda
                resp = e;
            }
        }
    }
    return resp;
}

function buscar(elementos) {
    let res = [];
    for (let e of elementos) {
        res.push(e.name);
        if (e.subcategories && e.subcategories.length > 0) {
            for (let sub of buscar(e.subcategories)) {
                 res.push(e.name + "/" + sub);
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}

console.log(BuscarPorRuta("products1",products));
console.log(BuscarPorRuta("products5",products));
console.log(BuscarPorRuta("products1/products2",products));
```